# PHP self-including loop (concept)

Tags: php, include

I have a curiosity. What happens if a PHP script includes itself?

The reason I ask is that I have a php file that generates the contents for all of my site's `<head>` tags. That includes the site's `404 error page` `head` tag.

If the php file that generates these `head` tags is accessed directly it "pretends" to not exist by including the `404 error page`, which sends `404 status` back to the client.

This is what the filesystem looks like:

```
/
  .htaccess <- (apache 404 handling)
  404.php <- 404 error page
  head.php <- '<head>' generator
  ...
```

`404.php` contains:

```
<?php
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
?>
<html>
    <head>
<?php
    $key = true;
    include dirname(__FILE__) . "/head.php";
?>
    </head>
    <body>
        lul. dead.
    </body>
</html>
```

`head.php` contains:

```
<?php
    if(isset($key) && $key===true){
        //code to generate <head> content
    }else{
        include dirname(__FILE__) . "/404.php";
    }
?>
```

`$key` tells `head.php` that it was included by another php file and not requested over URL.

So, to sum up, if I directly request `head.php` from my web browser (not accessing it via `php includes`, just via http request) it should:

**(a)** realize that the request was not an `include` from another php file, then 
**(b)** include `404.php`, which 
**(c)** sends a `404 status` on `line 2` of `404.php` and, then, 
**(d)** includes `head.php`.

Therefore, eventually `head.php` will include `head.php`.

does this happen?

Comment: I wasn't sure that this was going to work, so I am posting my own results here on the stack, so everyone else can see.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does.

**NOTE:** However, an internal server error can occur. For example:

`include.php`:

```
<?php
    if(!isset($s)){
        $s = 0;
    }
    if($s<10){
        include "include.php";
        $s++;
    }
?>
test
```

This script produces an internal server error. I did not check to see how many times a file can be self-included before the error occurs, but apparently 10 times is (or is more than) enough times to cause the error.

Either that or a PHP script can not directly include itself. It has to do so through including a separate script which includes the original script

Comment: I wasn't sure that this was going to work, so I am posting my own results here on the stack, so everyone else can see.